# Имеет ли смысл использование SCSS при именовании классов по BEM?

Tags: html, scss

Есть такой SCSS-код (вложенность блоков с именованием классов по BEM):

```
.banner {
    свойства
    &__text {
        свойства
    }
    &__img {
        свойства
    }
}
```

Есть ли смысл в таком написании стилей, использую вложенность при именовании классов по BEM?
Или лучше делать без вложенности?

```
.banner {
    свойства
}

.banner__text {
    свойства
}

.banner__img  {
    свойства
}
```

Т.к. например, при правке стилей класс найти проще, если стили написаны без вложенности.